# Как заменить определённые строки частично в python

Tags: python, текст

Допустим есть текстовый файл

```
"USER" "DAN"
"POINTS" "240"
"PERMAPOINTS" "2"
"USER" "MIKE"
"POINTS" "330"
"PERMAPOINTS" "1"
```

и нужно чтобы во всех строках с "POINTS"
значение увеличилось в 2 раза, но не было тронуто PERMAPOINTS.
Я не знаю какие модули для этого нужны и как это сделать. Спасибо всем кто попытается помочь.
UPD Спасибо всем за помощь я разобрался.

Comment: читайте построчно файл, проверяйте наличие "POINTS", для таких строк ищите, что во вторых кавычках, переводите в инт и увеличивайте, сохраняйте в файл... на чистом пайтоне, без модулей

Comment: ознакомьтесь https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/fajly-rabota-s-fajlami.html